# I cannot connect to postgres using pgAdmin. they both run in docker containers

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin

i have got this docker compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres:latest
    hostname: host.docker.internal
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "postgres@localhost.com"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "postgres"
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: "False"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres

volumes:
  pg-data:
  pgadmin-data:

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
```

when i try to connect to postgres through pg admin in browser it says - "Unable to connect. Connection failed"
pgAdmin works good and as expected.
Postgres container works also good except that i cannot connect to postgres, but i can get into cli using docker desktop

I checked logs and saw nothing special.
I tried to use other ports but nothing changed too.
I tried to explicitly add containers to one network.
tried to add hostname to postgres container

I have read every single post on stackoverflow about this problem...

Comment: You have not told us what info you entered into pgAdmin in order to effect the connection.

Comment: Yes, i did not. And that was the problem. I should have used container name as host to connect to postgres inside one network instead of using localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you configure the server within pgadmin, did you use postgres_container for the hostname/address field?

Please check out this tutorial to compare to your case https://www.pintonista.com/connecting-pgadmin-to-postgres-container/

Comment: Thank you for really helpful tutorial. And your remark wes really helpful too. Because i used localhost or host that i defined in postgres container config trying to connect to postgres instead of using container name. I switched to container name and successfully connected to postgres..